# Start a program using cron job

Tags: cron

A vision system program runs on a PC and I need it to be always running and on top, But sometimes there may happen a problem in the program and terminate it. So I need a script to check if the program is not running and run it as well.

I used cron job to the task, I wrote this cron job to run the script:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/masoud/Desktop/vision3/cron.sh
```

and the cron.sh is :

```
cd "${0%/*}"
if pgrep -x "video" > /dev/null
then
    echo "running"
else
    /home/masoud/Desktop/vision3/video &
fi
```

The cron.sh do the job correct, the cron job runs the script but it terminate it briefly. I can see my webcam LED turns on for a second.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some programs read from or write to the console, and this will fail when run in cron.

At a quick thing, you may try changing the run line to be  `/home/masoud/Desktop/vision3/video >/dev/null </dev/null`.

Comment: @BrianC sorry but didn't help.

Comment: If you manually run the script from the command line, does it work? Is it failing only within cron?

Comment: @BrianC Yeah exactly. It is fine when I run the script from the command line.

Comment: Is this an interactive program or a daemon? Does it have its own window?

Comment: @StephenKitt No it is not an interactive program it just shows a view of the camera and the result of vision system on a window.

Comment: OK, it displays something on your desktop then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs aren't really suited to managing desktop applications. You'd be better off starting the application from a looping shell script; at its simplest

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/masoud/Desktop/vision3
while :; do ./vision; done
```

That way whenever `vision` stops, it will be started again.

You may want to plan an "exit strategy" for when you really want to stop the program. This would do:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/masoud/Desktop/vision3
while [ ! -f no_vision ]; do ./vision; done
```

Then when you want to stop the program,

```
touch /home/masoud/Desktop/vision3/no_vision
```

and close it — the shell script will stop too.